# How to add fonts to a MudTextField with MudBlazor API?

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have this MudBlazor component:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@_presentationSettingsServiceRequest.PostCode" Class="my-2" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AutoFocus="false" Style="color: #333333;"/>
```

I want to add fonts using a similar API like Typo="Typo.subtitle1" but I can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the typo parameters with the theme.

Please look at this:
https://mudblazor.com/customization/typography#change-default-font